# Pthreads doesnt know $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Tags: pthreads, server, document-root

Please i rly need help. Im calling multiple functions with pthreads .. everything works fine but i need include file in that functions and it doesnt work because $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is empty in Thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following anywhere in a script file to figure out your base path:

```
realpath(dirname(__FILE__))
```

Example: put this in /srv/www/domain.com/app/config.php will output:

```
/srv/www/domain.com/app
```

Make sure to use 'DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR' to add directory slashes:

```
realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
```

Comment: it is no exactly what i needed but i remembered about define constant so i made it but thx for answer